# Calling ASP.NET web handler via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, curl, ashx

I'm currently trying to call an .ashx file from my website to trigger a specific operation. The script expects 1 parameter that I also need to pass over. This needs to be done in PHP but even after several hours of trying I can not figure out how exactly this can be achieved.

I found a JavaScript code snipped which does exactly what I asked for but so far I could not extend its basic idea to my PHP script. Here is what it looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createXMLHttpRequest() {
   try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
   try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
   try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
   alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
   return null;
 }
var xmlHttpReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttpReq.open("GET", "http://target.ashx?id=myId", false);
xmlHttpReq.send(null);
</script>
```

I assume that the right way to approach this problem is using curl and I also found several explanations and tutorials on that matter but so far, nothing I included in my PHP script worked (I made sure that curl support is enabled). Currently, it looks like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://target.ashx?id=myId");
curl_exec($ch);
```

I also tried opening the URL by simply using fopen() in PHP but that does nothing at all.
So basically all I need is my PHP script to do what my JavaScript code already does.

Comment: why does it have to be PHP or what are you doing with the page you're trying to call?